# Puppeteer: Make browser seem less like a robot/script

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So basically I was just wondering if there are any ways to make a Puppeteer browser more believeable to a website in that they think it's an actual user and not a script. I already have a user-agent set using:

```
await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3844.0 Safari/537.36");
```

But almost all the buttons on the site that result in POST requests such as login buttons do nothing because it recognises the clicks, etc as not a legitimate user hence me wondering if there is anything else I can do when launching the browser to fix this apart from setting a user-agent...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: curious, why would you ever need something like that?

Comment: @AdamKosmala I'm trying to automate a tedious task on a website so that I can complete it quicker

Comment: Please show how you try to click those buttons that won't click.

Comment: @Vaviloff They click perfectly fine, but the response from the website is the issue. For example the login button I press (after I have entered the credentials) just comes up with a spinning icon non-stop whereas when I do that same action manually on a normal browser that login button works perfectly fine

Comment: Have you tried running your code with {headless : false } option? Are there any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `{slowMo: intValue}` in `puppeteer.launch()` options?

Maybe instead of using `page.click()` on the element, specify a mouse position, and move it a few times over the button, before clicking?

Try navigating the page yourself, within the puppeteer browser - using on keypresses (tab etc..) and see if that works? Then combine it w/ slowMo in a script?

I know there's also a puppeteer-extra-stealth library out there which does a lot of extra things in an attempt to obscure the client.